# Rails 3. Query for single items

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an API using Rails 3 and I am implementing a tag search. Each user can add their own custom tags, therefore when a user searches for a tag it is returned several times. For example when someone is searching for drupalcon and 10 people has added it it will appear ten times in the search results. I want it to appear only on time per tag.

This is my query code. How can I extend it to do such a search?

```
@tags = Tag.where("LOWER (tag) LIKE ?", "%#{@query}%").limit(1)
```

UPDATE

Solved it with this query.

```
@tags = Tag.select('DISTINCT tag').where("LOWER (tag) LIKE ?", "%#{@query}%")
```

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1):

You call `Tag.first` and pass it a `conditions` option.

```
@tag = Tag.first(:conditions => ["LOWER (tag) LIKE ?", "%#{@query}%"])
```

Comment: Mm, if there is other tags with "s" in it only one of them is displaying. So if I got the tags "sswc","superman" and a person is searching for "s" only "sswc" is showing. I want to be able to show ALL tags that got an "s" in them but only one of each kind.

Comment: Ended up using this and it works perfectly.
@tags = Tag.select('DISTINCT tag').where("LOWER (tag) LIKE ?", "%#{@query}%")